# Pass enum value as parameter in Apollo Client instead of a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-apollo

I have the following query in a React-Native application using Apollo Client:

```
query getCollection($sortKey: ProductCollectionSortKeys) { ... }
```

Now i need to pass the value PRICE as `sortKey` parameter. Note: not the string "PRICE" but the enum PRICE.

If I use this syntax I will send "PRICE" instead of PRICE as enum value:

```
getCollection({ variables: { sortKey: "PRICE" } });
```

I want to send something like:

```
sortKey: PRICE
```

and not:

```
sortKey: "PRICE"
```

Comment: Does it work though?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I mean does it work if you pass a `string`?

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli - Did you find the solution? I'm facing same issue currently, still researching the possible way to pass enum as param instead of string.

Comment: No, didn't find anything yet, sorry, it you will please let us know.